# ERROR: data type inet has no default operator class for access method "gist"

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.4, gist-index

Using PostgreSQL version `9.4.5`, I have a table that contains an `INET` column.
In that column I have a `gist` index

```
CREATE TABLE ipv4_prefix (
    id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4() NOT NULL,
    prefix inet NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ck_ipv4_prefix_valid_ipv4 CHECK ((family(prefix) = 4))
);
ALTER TABLE ONLY ipv4_prefix ADD CONSTRAINT pk_ipv4_prefix PRIMARY KEY (id);
CREATE INDEX ipv4_prefix_gist_index ON ipv4_prefix USING gist (prefix inet_ops);
```

This all seems to work:

```
mimir=# \d ipv4_prefix
              Table "ipv4_prefix"
 Column | Type |              Modifiers              
--------+------+-------------------------------------
 id     | uuid | not null default uuid_generate_v4()
 prefix | inet | not null
Indexes:
    "pk_ipv4_prefix" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ipv4_prefix_gist_index" gist (prefix inet_ops)
Check constraints:
    "ck_ipv4_prefix_valid_ipv4" CHECK (family(prefix) = 4)
```

However, when I try to add an `EXCLUDE` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE ipv6_prefix ADD CONSTRAINT ipv6_prefix_exclude_constraint EXCLUDE USING gist (prefix WITH &&);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  data type inet has no default operator class for access method "gist"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I still haven't found the documentation for this, but figured it out with some experimentation.

You need to add the [ops class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/gist-builtin-opclasses.html) after the column name while creating the constraint.

So `(prefix inet_ops WITH &&)` rather than `(prefix WITH &&)`

For those using SQLAlchemy, you can sneak this through:

```
class IPv4PrefixTable(IPPrefixTable):
    __tablename__ = 'ipv4_prefix'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('ipv4_prefix_gist_index', 'prefix', postgresql_using='gist', postgresql_ops={
            'prefix': 'inet_ops'
        }),
        ExcludeConstraint(('prefix inet_ops', '&&'), using='gist', name='ipv4_prefix_exclude_constraint'),
        {'schema': 'mimir'}
    )

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, server_default=func.uuid_generate_v4())
    prefix = Column(INET, CheckConstraint('family(prefix) = 4', name='valid_ipv4'), unique=False, nullable=False)
```

Comment: @jusha Inglis - Does this still work for you? i am getting errors with SQLAlchemy==1.3.11

Comment: @Alonme I don't know, sorry. It's been a while since I've used sqlalchemy in anger.